# include php code in caldera form plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

iam using wordpress for form submission.For creating form i have used caldera form plugin.
In this i need to create dynamic dropdown list the data retrive from database.how to write my php code in caldera form.pls anyone can say me how to include php code.

Thanks in advance